# java HashMap - how to retrieve both elements

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

Consider a part of program:-

```
HashMap<Object,Object> m1=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
Person p1=new Person("Raj","Sharma");
Person p2=new Person("Raj","Sharma");
m1.put(p1,"11");
m1.put(p2,"22");
```

> Also Person class have overridden hashCode() method but no equals() method

What i know is: Since both have same keys (p1 and p2 produce same hashcode), and thus they correspond to same index, so after storing p1 in that index, when it try put p2 JVM see that both have same hashCode, so again hashing is done on p2 and new index is generated and 22 gets stored on that index.

Now if we try to retrieve the element by using key p1 or p2,

```
String temp=(String)m1.get(p1);     // 11
```

it will return 11 only then how can we retrieve the element 22??

Comment: P1 is replaced by p2. So when you get value for this for. It will be the newest value the put in the map

Comment: there is no equals method in person class so p1 and p2 keys will get different indexes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Person class overrides both hashCode and equals, so that `p1.equals(p2)` is true and `p1.hashCode()==p2.hashCode()`, you can't retrieve both "11" and "22" from the Map, since HashMap doesn't allow duplicate keys.

Therefore `m1.put(p2,"22");` will replace the "11" value with "22". In that case, both `m1.get(p1)` and `m1.get(p2)` will return "22".

> Also Person class have overridden hashCode() method but no equals() method

I missed that sentence. If you don't override `equals`, p1 and p2 are not the same key, even if they have the same hashCode. `m1.get(p1)` will return "11" and `m1.get(p2)` will return "22".

Comment: I have doubt about last line you said.. >>>m1.get(p2) will return "22" but why?? p1 and p2 have same hashCode() value then why this will return 22 it should return 11 i think

Comment: @Ronaldo7 If both keys have the same hashCode, they'll be placed in the same bucket of the Map. The HashMap will distinguish between the two using `equals` (since you didn't override `equals`, p1 is not equal to p2).

Comment: can a bucket having a index can store two objects

Comment: @Ronaldo7 Each bucket has a linked list of all the Entries that were mapped to that bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the equals method of Person also. When trying to retrieve the value hashcode will be used to calculate which bucket to search in, but then equals method will be used to check if the passed in key exactly matches the key against which the value is stored in.

When working with hash based collections it's a must to override the equals and hashcode in Java. Please refer equals overriding contract here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)